# How to get string size in bytes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unicode

I see some questions that was answered back in 2011 way to get string size in bytes and some says it is impossible to calculate array of strings to get bytes,so I just want to ask do we have any better approach to get this task achieved ? I want to get total bytes of `$scope.event` array ?

ctrl.js

```
$scope.event = ['lorem ipsum fdsmfds,mfbs','lorem ipsum dsmfds,mfbs','lorem ipsum lorem ipsum'];

 var getCharCOdeData = $scope.event.map(function(word) {
        return word.split(' ').reduce(function(total, cur) {
            return total + cur.charCodeAt(0);
        }, 0);
    });
```

Comment: Firstly you need to know what encoding you're using.

Comment: [Here's an algorithm](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/37552/104089) from CodeReview for UTF-8.

Comment: I am consuming text using UTF-8 encoding

Comment: Simply do the for loop and keep adding if you want to know only the total.

Comment: Secondly you need to understand how much space javascript allocates in memory for a UTF8 encoded character